# Block bootstrap with indicator variable for each block

Tags: stata

I want to run block bootstrap, where the blocks are countries, and include country indicator variables. I thought the following would work.

```
regress mvalue kstock i.country, vce(bootstrap, cluster(country))
```

But I get the following error.

```
. regress mvalue kstock i.country, vce(bootstrap, cluster(country))
(running regress on estimation sample)

Bootstrap replications (50)
----+--- 1 ---+--- 2 ---+--- 3 ---+--- 4 ---+--- 5 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx    50
insufficient observations to compute bootstrap standard errors
no results will be saved
r(2000);
```

It seems that this should work. If the block bootstrap picks the same country for every block, then it seems it should just drop the intercept.

Is my error coding or conceptual? Here is some code using the `grunfeld` data.

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
xtset, clear
generate country = int((company - 1) / 2) + 1
regress mvalue kstock i.country, vce(bootstrap, cluster(country))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not with your coding, but is conceptual.   The problem is that you cannot identify each coefficient in each regression in each bootstrap sample.  Not all "countries" are included in the dataset for each bootstrap repetition.   You can diagnose what is going on with the `vce( , noisily)` sub-option:

```
. regress mvalue kstock i.bscountry, vce(bootstrap, cluster(country) noisily)
```

Errors are generated because some coefficients are missing when the regression runs with particular bootstrap samples.  In each regression you can see that some countries dummies are being omitted due to collinearity. This should be expected and makes a lot of sense -- the country dummies could =0 for all observations in the bootstrap sample if the country was not drawn!

If you are really trying to estimate the coefficients on the country dummies, you are going to have to find another approach than bootstrapping with K clusters if K is the number of countries. If you don't care about the coefficient dummies you could use another command that simply absorbs the fixed effects and only reports the coefficients on the other independent variables (e.g., `areg` or `xtreg`).   One way think  about what is going on is that it is analogous to this:

```
.bootstrap, cluster(country) idcluster(bscountry) noisily: regress mvalue kstock i.bscountry
```

With the `idcluster()` option, each country that is drawn in a bootstrap sample is given its own ID number.  If a country is drawn twice then there are two dummies. (The coefficients for the two dummies naturally turn out to be identical or near-identical.)  However, the coefficients in this output are are completely meaningless because `bscountry` "2" will be different countries in different bootstrap iterations.  Since you would ignore any output on the dummies, you might as well use a model like `areg` or `xtreg` since they run more quickly.

Although there are many applications where bootstrapping with clusters would work fine, the problem here is the inclusion of cluster dummies in the regression. This all begs the question of whether this exercise makes any sense at all. If you are trying to estimate the coefficients for the country dummies, then certainly not. Otherwise, the solutions above might be OK, but it is hard to say without knowing your research question.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought having all zeros in an indicator would be OK. I guess Stata doesn't know that I don't care about the indicators unless I tell it. :) Thanks for the tip to use `areg` and the reminder that `noisily` works in this context, too.